# How to break one Functional Resnet50 model into multiple layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created Resnet50 using:

```
     base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    base_model.trainable = True
    
    inputs = Input((224, 224, 3))
    h = base_model(inputs, training=True)
    model = Model(inputs, projection_3)
```

model summary:

```
Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_image (InputLayer)    [(None, 256, 256, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 resnet50 (Functional)       (None, 8, 8, 2048)        23587712  
                                                                 
=================================================================
```

Later, I realized I need to access some layer like this:

```
Resmodel.layers[4].output
```

However, I got:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there away to break the Resnet50 funcational model into mutpile layer OR ***there away to access a certain layer of the model***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**model.layers[1].layers[4]**